# SQL to disable duplicate rows (Postgres)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using a Postgres database, and have the following table.

```
                  LOB
+-------+------+-----------+----------+
| lobid | name | companyid | disabled |
+-------+------+-----------+----------+
|   1   | abc  |    101    | false    |
+-------+------+-----------+----------+
|   2   | abc  |    101    | false    |
+-------+------+-----------+----------+
|   3   | def  |    102    | false    |
+-------+------+-----------+----------+
|   4   | def  |    103    | false    |
+-------+------+-----------+----------+
|   5   | ghi  |    103    | false    |
+-------+------+-----------+----------+
```

I would like to write a query to SELECT all duplicates that are not disabled for the same company. i.e. same `name` and `companyid`.

e.g.

```
+-------+------+-----------+----------+
| lobid | name | companyid | disabled |
+-------+------+-----------+----------+
|   1   | abc  |    101    | false    |
+-------+------+-----------+----------+
|   2   | abc  |    101    | false    |
+-------+------+-----------+----------+
```

Then I would like an UPDATE sql statement to update all the duplicates to disabled `true`. However it should leave one (any one) row enabled. i.e. so there is just singles and no duplicates.

e.g.

```
+-------+------+-----------+----------+
| lobid | name | companyid | disabled |
+-------+------+-----------+----------+
|   1   | abc  |    101    | false    |
+-------+------+-----------+----------+
|   2   | abc  |    101    | true     |
+-------+------+-----------+----------+
|   3   | def  |    102    | false    |
+-------+------+-----------+----------+
|   4   | def  |    103    | false    |
+-------+------+-----------+----------+
|   5   | ghi  |    103    | false    |
+-------+------+-----------+----------+
```

I have tried the following, but it is not correct. I am still seeing dome singles in the result set:

```
select l.* 
from lob l 
where l.disabled = false  
and l.companyid in (
select companyid
  from lob 
  group by name, companyid, disabled
  having count(*) > 1 and disabled = false)
order by l.companyid, l.name
```

**UPDATE**

Thanks to Rory O'Connells answer below, I run this SQL:

```
UPDATE lob SET disabled = true WHERE lobid IN 
(select l.lobid 
from lob l 
join ( 
    select min(lobId) as lobId, name, companyid
    from lob 
    where disabled = false
    group by name, companyid, disabled
    having count(*) > 1
) k on l.name = k.name and l.companyid = k.companyid
where l.disabled = false  
and l.lobId > k.lobId
order by l.companyid, l.name)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so you need to identify the companies/ids where there is a problem (as you have done):

```
select min(lobId) as keepId, name, companyid
from lob 
where disabled = false
group by name, companyid, disabled
having count(*) > 1
```

From these, you only want to leave 1 company record with disabled = false, correct? So you need to update those which are not equal to the minimum row id (or maximum row id, pick one).

So use a join here.  Get the minimum value (This also filters out companies where there is no record to update).

```
select l.* 
from lob l 
join ( 
    select min(lobId) as keepId, name, companyid
    from lob 
    where disabled = false
    group by name, companyid, disabled
    having count(*) > 1
) k on l.name = k.name and l.companyid = k.companyid
where l.disabled = false  
and l.lobId > k.lobId
order by l.companyid, l.name
```

Then when you're happy, update disabled = true based on l.lobId

Comment: Hi Rory, thanks for your answer. It looks correct, but I am a little confused by the result set it produces (I was having the same issue with my query). It looks like some of the results are not duplicates. (See the UPDATE to my original post above).

Comment: I think if you look at the ones which don't appear as a duplicate (i.e. select * where name = x and id = y) you will find they are duplicated. Remember, the test excludes one record (where id = minimum id) so you're looking at the set of records to fix, not the full set of duplicate records.

Comment: Oh yes, that makes sense, it shows just the rows that have duplicates (i.e. the ones to be updated).

Answer (score 2):

For Postgres version > 9.1 (i think), you can use something like this:

```
;WITH src as
(
  SELECT lobid, name, companyid, disabled, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY companyid, name ORDER BY disabled) rn
  FROM lob
)
UPDATE lob
SET disabled = 'true'
FROM src 
WHERE lob.lobid = src.lobid AND src.rn>1;

SELECT *
FROM lob
ORDER BY lobid;
```

[DbFiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oddpr3s19eEVroZAGwGQQE/0)

For further details, please see: [PostgreSQL: UPDATE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html)

Comment: @Richard . . . This is a *much* better solution for an `update`.

Comment: Thank you, @GordonLinoff. Much appreciate it. With respect, Maciej.